# Making a field as un editable conditionally

Tags: apex, formula, validation, validation-rule, edit

I have detail page on which I have created two fields - PageNumber__c and Book__c.

I have a requirement that if the pageNumber__C is populated with a value then the Book__c field should not be edited. How can I do this?

What I think - Can I make a validation rule, which would check if pageNumber__c is not null then if book__c isChanged() then throw an error. Is this approach possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, Validation rule is the right approach here.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me the syntax on how the formula would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a validation rule with a formula something like this..

```
AND(
  NOT(ISBLANK(pageNumber__C)),
  ISCHANGED(Book__c)
)
```